# How to get X509Certificate field in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xml, x509certificate, xml-signature

I’m trying to Sign a XML document in iOS. I already created a digestValue and a SignatureValue using a pfx file, but I cannot generate the X509Certificate field inside KeyInfo field. I know I only need the pfx file to generate this, but how could I do it in iOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I had to import OpenSSL lib to my project as a pod:

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', '~> 1.0'
```

Then I created an Objective-C file to use the C functions of OpenSSL, and use the following functions to get the PEM value:

- d2i_PKCS12: read certificate
- PKCS12_parse: parse the certificate to X509 object.
- PEM_write_bio_X509: parse the X509 data to a BIO object.
- BIO_get_mem_ptr: parse the BIO data to a MEM data

Then I allocated a NSString using the mem->data, and there is the Certificate PEM value.

For more details about the functions, I followed this documentation: 
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/